# How to install additional packages for pyspark in AWS EMR cluster?

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a pyspark application that uses boto3 library under the hood.

I am trying to launch application with built wheel package that contains dependency of applications.

External dependency like boto3 I installed via bootstraping actions of emr cluster.

```bash
sudo python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade                                                                                                           
sudo python3 -m pip install boto3==1.24.83
```

I specified manually spark.pyspark.python option to python3 in cluster configuration.

And I can not solve problem with absence of package

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

UPD:
I tried to run it without sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by specifying a bootstrap actions within the cluster configuration , more details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-install-kernels-libs.html)

#### Example - Bootstrap

`boostrap .sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo python3 -m pip install \
    botocore \
    boto3
```

Comment: I am passing path to bootstrap script that I pushed to s3
Like this 
--bootstrap-actions Path="${ARTIFACT_STORE}/bootstrap.sh" \

Comment: You can wrap this up inside a cluster bootup script